# BodyPosition not changing?

Tags: roblox

I've been sitting at my laptop for about an hour trying to figure out what's going on. I did this exact same thing yesterday and it worked. Please help.

Explaining the program:
The program takes the object that the mouse is pointing at, if you click the object gravitates toward the mouse.

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local runservice = game:GetService("RunService")
local character = player.Character
local humanoid = character.Humanoid
local camera = workspace.Camera
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local mousepos = mouse.hit.p
local grabbed = false

local function grabbedobj(obj) --this is the thing i need help on
    local bodypos = obj.BodyPosition.Position
    local pos = obj.Position
    obj.Anchored = false
    mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
        grabbed = true
    end)
    mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function()
        grabbed = false
    end)
    if grabbed == true then
        print(obj.BodyPosition.Position)
        bodypos = Vector3.new(mousepos.X, mousepos.Y, mousepos.Z) --really important
    end
    if grabbed == false then
        bodypos = Vector3.new(pos.X, -25, pos.Z)
        pos = Vector3.new(bodypos.X, pos.Y, bodypos.Z)
    end
end

local function setup()
    mousepos = mouse.hit.p
    if mouse.Target ~= nil and mouse.Target.Parent == game.Workspace.IntObj then
        grabbedobj(mouse.Target) --takes object that the mouse is pointing at
    end
end

while wait(.1) do
    setup()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets shuffle the code a little bit so it does what I think you want to do. You might have mixed up some things while trying to debug this. So here:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local grabbed = false
local obj

mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()
    if mouse.Target ~= nil and mouse.Target.Parent == game.Workspace.IntObj then
        obj = mouse.Target
        obj.Anchored = false
        grabbed = true
    end
end)

mouse.Button1Up:Connect(function()
    if (grabbed) then
        grabbed = false--BodyPosition
        obj.BodyPosition.Position = Vector3.new(obj.Position.X, 0.1, obj.Position.Z)
        obj.Anchored = true
    end
end)

local function move()
    if (grabbed) then
        local mousepos = mouse.hit.p
        obj.BodyPosition.Position = Vector3.new(mousepos.X, mousepos.Y, mousepos.Z)
        print(obj.BodyPosition.Position)
    end
end

while wait(.1) do
    move()
end
```

When you click the mouse it checks if you click your part that is in IntObj. It will retain a reference to that part and then moves it with the mouse. When you release the button it will drop it at its location.

So this LocalScript should work but it has an issue updating the BodyPosition as you said in the title. The reason for that is that you can only update server parts from your client if you give the client permission from the server for it. You could write a remote function on the server and say:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction.OnServerInvoke = function(plr)
    Workspace.IntObj.Part:SetNetworkOwner(plr)
end
```

If you call this from your local script's initialization, it will work. Note, that your part cannot be anchored for that.

Another way would be to just let the server do the updating. So instead of setting the 
obj.BodyPosition.Position on the client you would call the remote function like this:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction:InvokeServer(Vector3.new(mousepos.X, mousepos.Y, mousepos.Z))
```

and then on the server you set the position:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.RemoteFunction.OnServerInvoke = function(plr, bodyPos)
    script.Parent.BodyPosition.Position = bodyPos
end
```

In that case, if you anchor/unanchor the part, do that on the server as well. Otherwise you'll get weird results.